# Razor add new attribute to HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to add a new attribute to my HTML dynamically, but I can't figure out how to do this;

I have some Facebook like button code, where I want to add a "data-url" attribute if the Url property in my model is specified.

I've tried a couple of things but this is what my code looks like now:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Url)) { data-url="@Model.Url" } data-text="@Model.TweetText" data-count="vertical" data-via="avalaxy">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

This does not work. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you want to use the `<text>` tag, with something like:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Url)) { <text>data-url="@Model.Url"</text> } data-text="@Model.TweetText" data-count="vertical" data-via="avalaxy">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: I, sir, believe you are the hero of the day. Thank you very much for solving this silly little problem of mine.

Comment: This is also the only way to have conditional data attributes, even in the newest version of Razor.